# emailing formatted data with PHP_XLSXWriter

Tags: php, xlsx

I've been using PHP_XLSXWriter, and I really like how simple and fast it is, but i haven't been able to get the formatting to work via email. I've tried various color formats for the fill, though the documentation seems to use 3 character hex.

here's the function that produces the xl format. 
as you can see, i just want the fill for the 1st row

```
function create_xl_string($data) {
$writer = new XLSXWriter();
  $rowdata=array('dr1','rp','RoutePattern','TOD','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','locNames','1D_Minutes','1D_ACD','1W_Minutes','locations','defrate','maxcost','ptLoss','projLoss','modified','description');
 $rowstyle=array('fill'=>"#FC0",'fill'=>"#FC0",'fill'=>"#FC0",'fill'=>"#CCC",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#09F",'fill'=>"#CC9",'fill'=>"#999",'fill'=>"#999",'fill'=>"#999",'fill'=>"#CC9",'fill'=>"#99C",'fill'=>"#99C",'fill'=>"#99C",'fill'=>"#99C",'fill'=>"#9C6",'fill'=>"#9C6");

 $writer->writeSheetRow('routes', $rowdata, $rowstyle );
 foreach($data as $datarow){
   $writer->writeSheetRow('routes',$datarow);
 }

return $writer->writeToString();
}
```

and here's the email function:

```
function emailL($filename1,$subject,$file1){
$multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';
$attch1 = chunk_split(base64_encode($file1));
$instruction ="report for today. ";

        $headers = array(
            "From: a@mydomain.net",
            "Reply-To: a@mydomain.net",
            "CC: b@mydomain.net",
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
        );

        $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$instruction\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
        . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename1 . ".xlsx\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$attch1\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep--";
        mail("me@mydomain.nett", $subject , $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

and here's the call:

```
emailL($filenameL,$filenameL,create_xl_string($totalarrayL) );
```

do i need to use a different format for the styles? is the issue perhaps the content-type? 
as an aside, i couldn't find it specifically mentioned in the documentation, but is there a way to pre-set column widths

Answer (score 0):

issue was that i had an older version of the PHP_xlsxwriter code. someone pointed me to the new version and i got it working